# How to use a paginated api with angular 11

Tags: angular

I am writing an angular client to work with a paginated api. I just need to implement the next button. How can I do that?

Pin list component.html

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let e of lis ;">
    <td><b>{{e["name"]}}</b></td>
    <td><b>{{e["about"]}}</b></td>
    <td><b><a target="_blank" href='https://ipfs.io/ipfs/{{e["hash"]}}'>{{e["hash"]}}</a></b></td>
    <td><b>{{e["date"]}}</b></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Pin list component ts

```
export class PinlistComponent implements OnInit {
  li:any;
  lis=[];
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.apiService.getPins().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.li=data;
      this.lis=this.li.pins;
    });
  }
  
}
```

Api service ts

```
  public getPins(){
    return this.httpClient.get(`https://openpinner.mycryptowebs.com:4000/`);
  }
```

The server side pagination will be like

> https://openpinner.mycryptowebs.com:4000/?page=1 (Page variable 10
> results per page)

I just want to implement a next and previous button. How can I do that? All the tutorials i am seeing on internet is with some plugins or libraries I dont want to use any of those I just want to use pure angular.

Comment: Your server will have to send you out the page number with the data. Your next() function will just increment it and set the incremented value in the request url.

Comment: server is already doing it I just want to impliment it with angular. How to do that?

Comment: where are you collecting the page number? all i see is this.li=data;
      this.lis=this.li.pins;

Comment: I dont know how to do that thats why I am asking the question. Server side is already paginated.

Comment: you need to tell server that you want paginated data and give them the info to serve data accordingly, so you need to put in your request all info to recognise what data do you want

Comment: I dont know how to do that in angular Can you please show me that? Am relativley new to angular

Comment: @arunwebber I just posted answer it should give you an idea about what I'm talking about. I haven't checked all the code so there might be a compile error of 2 but the general idea is correct. I think ;)

Comment: I have added comment on your answers

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiService.getPins().subscribe((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
  this.li=data;
  this.lis=this.li.pins;
  this.pageNumber=data.pageNumber //You say the server is sending this out
});
```

Change your service.

```
 public getPins(pageNumber:number){
   const url = 'https://openpinner.mycryptowebs.com:4000/'
   if(pageNumber)
     url += '?page=pageNumber'
   return this.httpClient.get(url);

 }
```

Your next function:

```
private next(){
   const nextPage=this.pageNumber+1
   this.apiService.getPins(nextPage).subscribe((data)=>{
  //use the data
  })       
}
```

In your html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let e of lis ;">
  <td><b>{{e["name"]}}</b></td>
  <td><b>{{e["about"]}}</b></td>
  <td><b><a target="_blank" href='https://ipfs.io/ipfs/{{e["hash"]}}'> 
  {{e["hash"]}}</a></b></td>
  <td><b>{{e["date"]}}</b></td>
 </tr>
 <button (click)="next()"></button>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How do I call the next() function?

Comment: Also server is not senting the page number but if the post request is having the page = 1 or 2 or 3 or its get incrimented the server will respond accordingly.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out the page number yourself. Based on your requests. YOu should also do a bit more reading on angular. There's plenty of beginner tutorials out there. Put aside a few hours and you'll start to get the hang of it.

Comment: I dont want to show apage number it just has to be incrimented and decrimented when ever the user clicks the next button or previou button that will do.

Comment: You need to know what it is in order to increment it. So your first query will have a page of 0 or 1 (depending on you r server setup) and just keep track of the next or previous clicks

Comment: Its showing just 1 from angular its not getting increment. Also when the page go incrimented the dom content is remining as same this code has to be like this `public getPins(pageNumber:number){
   const url = 'https://openpinner.mycryptowebs.com:4000/'
   if(pageNumber)
     url += '?page=' + pageNumber
   return this.httpClient.get(url);

 }`

Comment: See the plus sign becose the page no is a variable.

Comment: And the output how do i injuct it to dom? Dom content is remaining as same.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you anymore. You need to do some basic research first.  There's a load of free tutorials on youtube.

Comment: Code change `export class PinlistComponent implements OnInit {
  pageNumber = 1;
  li:any;
  lis=[];
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.apiService.getPins(this.pageNumber).subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log('Page No:',this.pageNumber);
      console.log(data);
      this.li=data;
      this.lis=this.li.pins;
    });
  }
  next(){
     const nextPage= this.pageNumber +1
     this.apiService.getPins(nextPage).subscribe((data)=>{
       console.log(data);
       this.li=data;
       this.lis=this.li.pins;
    })
  }
}`

Comment: html  ` <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let e of lis ;">
        <td><b>{{e["name"]}}</b></td>
        <td><b>{{e["about"]}}</b></td>
        <td><b><a target="_blank" href='https://ipfs.io/ipfs/{{e["hash"]}}'>{{e["hash"]}}</a></b></td>
        <td><b>{{e["date"]}}</b></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <button (click)="next()"> Next</button> `

Comment: and service .ts `  public getPins(pageNumber:number){
    console.log('Page No2:',pageNumber);
    let url = 'https://openpinner.mycryptowebs.com:4000/'
    if(pageNumber)
        url += '?page=' + pageNumber
        console.log('Url:',url);
    return this.httpClient.get(url);
  }` Only problem is that the page no variable will only incriment once and it stays same How can i change that?